# Calling the default event handler from my custom click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I am using jQuery to implement event delegation on my page. I define a click handler for the top level element, but only want to do something "custom" if the click fell on an element of certain class:

```
$("#myDivWithManyLinks").click(function(e){
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (target.hasClass('myClass123')
   {
       // do my "custom thing"
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
       // XXX let the click be handled by the click handler that would otherwise get it
   }
```

How can I do "XXX"?

Comment: What do you mean "how can I do XXX"? XXX will run if target does not have class myClass123.

Answer (score 0):

write a handler function and then reference it in else:

```
   $("#myDivWithManyLinks").click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.hasClass('myClass123')
    {
       // do my "custom thing"
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       handler(e);
    }
   });
   function handler(e){
      // what you want all links that don't have your special class to do
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about [preventDefault()](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/Events):

```
$("#myDivWithManyLinks").click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.hasClass('myClass123')
    {
       e.preventDefault();
       //do custom stuff
    }

   });
```